# Multiple pauses in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had a look through a lot of 'pause' solutions on this site but can't find one that fits my needs - I'm creating a number of javascript/jquery animations that have a lot of text in them, and need to pause the animations to give the user time to read the text before continuing. I assume I need to use the `setTimeout()` command, but my understanding of it is that it's used to call the next required function once the time is up; however, this would mean chopping my animations into hundreds of different functions each, which I really don't want to do!

My ideal solution would be something like:

```
function animateThis(){
  $('#sprite1').animate(....);
  setText(text1);
  $('#sprite2').animate(....);
  setText(text2);
  etc...
}

function setText(whichText){
  $('#txtBox').html(whichText);
  >> PAUSE BEFORE CONTINUING THE animateThis() FUNCTION, BUT AFTER CHANGING THE TEXT
}
```

I'm sure there must be a way of doing this, but I just can't figure it out - any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't you add them to the effects queue, and call `setText()` from the `complete` function?

Comment: You could implement your logic using delay()

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [JQuery timing library](http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/) is great for sticking non-animation time delays in to JQuery as it uses the same syntax as queuing multiple animations calls.

http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/

It allows delays, repeats and all sorts of other options.